# Text file has 1 or 2 or 3 strings followed by doubles. How do I read strings?(each line has 1 or 2 or 3 string in the beginning)

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I'm still new to c++(and to stackoverflow).
I'm creating program to analyze some data for me(open file, save data into vectors, then I search vectors for name, and then I work with objects functions). Anyways, previous "version" of the program works fine, but file that I open only contains 1 string per line in the beginning(followed by other data), so it's easy to work with.

What I'm trying to do, is to open up the files that contain 1-3 strings(i.e. line 1 - West Ham United, line 2 - Everton etc.). After the name, other data follows on the same line.

I thought about separating the name and other data into 2 lines, in example Line1 - name, Line2 - other data, and so on. But how do I save the whole "name" line into vector(vector is of the object type). Other option would be to open up the file and saving all of the chars into an array. Afterwards I would output that array in Outfile, deleting the spaces only between letters(i.e. - WestHamUnited), and then I would work with the output file.

Question is, how do I delete the spaces only between letters? 
Maybe you guys could recommend some other option that I'm not aware of.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code, explain what you expect it to do and also what you are seeing it actually does. SO is no coding service. You need to show some research effort. Finally, present a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What code do you need? Char array or getline?

Comment: Since you control the file format, put the fixed data first and the name (with possible spaces) last on each line.

Comment: I download files from Internet, and formatting each one will take some time. Moreover, I thought that it would be a good exercise for me

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :) You should edit your question and add at least some more pieces of information: 1. An actual sample input file (a few lines are enough, add four spaces before each line for correct formatting). 2. A MCVE with the code you have tried so far. 3. A description of what's wrong with the runtime behavior of your code.

Comment: You shouldn't actually manually edit your input format if it can be avoided. Only if it would be too hard (or impossible) to write a parser for the input format I would consider changing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose there is text line stored in `string` object (`s` can be read from file/stream by `getline`)

```
 std::string s = "Manchester City 17 26 2.16";
```

and we need to read all text before the first number to other `string` (join some words without spaces)

```
 std::string name = ""; // empty string to store name
```

We do not know how many non-numbers (parts of name) will be until the first number is in the string, but we expect that number is.

If your task is something like that, consider the following example:

```cpp
    std::istringstream ss(s);  // creation of stream object to read data from text line
    double d = 0; // will be the first number 
    std::string str; // buffer string for parts of name
    bool notNumber;
    // loop that works to update name trying to find a number
    do{
        ss >> d; // try to read number
        notNumber = ss.fail(); // save the state (if number was read value is false)
        if (notNumber) // is value is true (not a number is the first in the stream)
        {
            ss.clear(); // reset the state
            ss >> str; // read a word
            name.append(str); // add this word to the name
        }
    } while (notNumber && !ss.eof()); // while non-numbers are read and stream is not empty
    // after loop we have name and, perhaps, number
    std::cout << "Name is: " << name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The first number is: " << d << std::endl;
```

**UPDATE:**

Actually we can use `notNumber` to know that number was really present in the initial string `s`

```
if (notNumber)
    std::cout << "There is no number after name!" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "The first number is: " << d << std::endl;
```

**UPDATE 2:**

For file `test.txt` comprising

> West Ham United 3.14 22
>
> Everton 17 26 2.16
>
> Manchester City 9.32 17 26

the following program

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    // data structure to store data from file
    map<string, vector<double>> dataTable;
    // open the file
    ifstream inFile("test.txt");
    if (!inFile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File error!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    // reading data from file
    while (!inFile.eof() && inFile.good())
    {
        string s;
        string name;
        getline(inFile, s);
        istringstream ss(s);
        double d = 0;
        string str;
        bool notNumber;
        do{
            ss >> d;
            notNumber = ss.fail();
            if (notNumber)
            {
                ss.clear();
                ss >> str;
                name.append(str);
            }
        } while (notNumber && !ss.eof());
        if (name.length() == 0)
            continue;
        // saving numbers to table
        do{
            dataTable[name].push_back(d);
            ss >> d;
        } while (!ss.fail());
    }
    inFile.close();
    // print data stored in table
    for (map<string, vector<double>>::iterator i = dataTable.begin(); i != dataTable.end(); i++)
    {
        cout << i->first << " : ";
        for (vector<double >::iterator j = i->second.begin(); j != i->second.end(); j++)
        {
            cout << *j << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

provides the following output:

[image]

Comment: thanks! That works, but only reads the first line, somewhy. so I do getline(inFile, s), I tried for and while(!inFIle.eof()) loops, but they give some strange outputs.

Comment: @illia I have added one more example, try it on your data and if you still have problem, make one more question posting your code, input sample and explanation of output problem

Comment: I have a Team.h. In main I create vector of Tea, type(vector<Team>teams;), and I read all the data in that vector. I guess I'll post new question and I'll try to post some basic code of what I mean. Thanks though!

Comment: Of course, you should change my `map<string, vector<double>>` to your `vector<Team>` and provide appropriate reading of string(s) and number(s) to fields of `Team`, but I think you have all examples to make you task without asking new question. Good luck!

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll definitely try it!)

Answer (score 0):

"Question is, how do I delete the spaces only between letters?"

You are aware of [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/), aren't you? Then you should be able to locate a method that deletes a character or character range from the string.

Good. Than the only problem would be how to detect if a character is a space. How hard could it be, I wonder.

I short: RTFM, Luke, use it with full confidence.

Comment: I don't need character range. Let's say I have
Line1 - Manchester City 17 26 2.16
Line2 - Everton 23 17 3.05
In the first line I'll only need to delete the spaces between r and C, whereas in Line2 I don't need to delete anything. Here's what I want it to look afterwards:
Line1 - ManchesterCity 17 26 2.16
Line2 - Everton 23 17 3.05
There's gonna be over 50 files(20+ items in each), with different names, and deleting character range from each one doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: @illia so, did you find the method(s) of the std::string which do what you need?

Answer (score 0):

If you can control input file format, I would recommend you to introduce some delimiter mark for the first column.

Otherwise, if the number of columns is fixed, you can read line in reverse. E.g. the latest 3 words are numbers and all the rest is team's name.

Note, that it is wrong just read words until the first digit, because there are exist teams with numbers in name (e.g. FC Schalke 04).

Here is an example:

```
struct FileLine
{
    std::string col1;
    double col2 = 0., col3 = 0., col4 = 0.;

    // `words` is a vector of words from a line in file
    bool load(const std::vector<std::string>& words)
    {
        col1.clear();
        col2 = col3 = col4 = 0.;

        std::vector<std::string>::size_type n = words.size();
        if (n >= 4) {
            col4 = std::stod(words.at(n-1));
            col3 = std::stod(words.at(n-2));
            col2 = std::stod(words.at(n-3));
            col1 = std::accumulate(words.begin(), words.end()-3, col1);
        }

        return n >= 4;
    }
};
```

Another way is to use regular expressions ([link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)). It's very powerful tool for a text parsing.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't thought about the teams with numbers in them(Konoplyanka might move to Schalke, in case you're a Schalke fan).
Another question. Why use std::(i.e. std:: string instead of just string)?

Comment: To avoid name collisions. It's not a good practice to use 'using namespace'. No, I'm not a Schalke fan yet :-)