# Reading unknown number of strings followed by doubles into a vector

Tags: c++, c++11

So, I want need to open a file which contains football team names followed by other data. Example would be:

```
Leicester City 38 12 13
West Ham 38 14 15
Schalke04 40 16 17
```

Then, I read that data into a vector of object type(I have "Team.h"). Problem is, some teams contain only 1 string as a name, others have 2 or more, some even have numbers in the name(i.e.Schalke04). So, how do I open a file and read info in vector correctly?

```
#ifndef TEAM_H
#define TEAM_H

#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Team
{
public:
    Team();
    Team(string, double, double, double);
    string getName();
    double getn1();
    double getn2();
    double getn3();

private:
    string name;
    double n1;
    double n2;
    double n3;

};
#endif
```

Team.cpp

```
#include "Team.h"

Team::Team()
{

}

Team::Team(string n, double N1, double N2, double N3)
{
    name = n;
    n1 = N1;
    n2 = n2;
    n3 = N3;
}

string Team::getName()
{
    return name;
}

double Team::getn1()
{
    return n1;
}

double Team::getn2()
{
    return n2;
}

double Team::getn3()
{
    return n3;
}
```

Usually reading in vector would look like this

```
inFile >> name >> n1 >> n2 >> n3;
Team newTeam(name, n1, n2, n3);
teams.push_back(newTeam) //vector<Team>teams declared earlier
```

UPD:My search method(not good)

```
string homeTeam;
Team ht;
for (Team team: newTeams)
{
     if(team.getName() == homeTeam)
     {
        ht = team;
     }
}
```

Comment: You would probably be better off reading the whole line in, and then parsing it for tokens using string stream.

Comment: Do you have any control over the file format? It could be easier if, for example, names were surrounded by quotes. Or if values were separated by a comma or any other separator (CSV file).

Comment: @MikMik, I do have control, and I can even create a file myself, but I will have over 60 files, with over 50 doubles after name(20+lines per file). But no, names are not surrounded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change `Team.h` and `Team.cpp` consider adding

```
friend istream &operator>>(istream &input, Team &t);
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, Team &t);
```

for reading data from input stream to object of `Team` class and output whole object to the output stream.

I mean the following:

**Team.h**

```cpp
#ifndef TEAM_H
#define TEAM_H

#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Team
{
public:
    Team();
    Team(string, double, double, double);
    string getName();
    double getn1();
    double getn2();
    double getn3();
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &input, Team &t);
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, Team &t);
private:
    string name;
    double n1;
    double n2;
    double n3;

};
#endif
```

**Team.cpp (only new lines based on [answer to related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39218271/text-file-has-1-or-2-or-3-strings-followed-by-doubles-how-do-i-read-stringsea/39231681#39231681))**

```cpp
istream &operator>>(istream &input, Team &t)
{
    while (!input.eof() && input.good())
    {
        string s;
        string name;
        getline(input, s);
        if (input.bad() || s.length() == 0)
        {
            input.setstate(ios::badbit); // for case of empty line
            return input;
        }
        istringstream ss(s);
        string str;
        bool notNumber;
        do{
            ss >> t.n1;
            notNumber = ss.fail();
            if (notNumber)
            {
                ss.clear();
                ss >> str;
                //if(name.length() > 0) name.append(" "); // uncomment this if you want spaces in name
                name.append(str);
            }
        } while (notNumber && !ss.eof());
        if (name.length() == 0)
            continue;
        t.name = name;
        if (notNumber)
        {
            input.setstate(ios::badbit);
            return input;
        }
        ss >> t.n2;
        ss >> t.n3;
        if (ss.fail())
        {
            input.setstate(ios::badbit);
            return input;
        }
        return input;
    }
    return input;
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, Team &t)
{
    output << t.getName() << " " << t.getn1() << " " << t.getn2() << " " << t.getn3();
    return output;
}
```

And usage will be like that:

```
// reading data from file
vector<Team> dataTable;
while (!inFile.eof() && !inFile.bad())
{
    Team tmp;
    inFile >> tmp;
    if (!inFile.fail())
        dataTable.push_back(tmp);
    else
        inFile.clear();
}
// print data stored in table
for (vector<Team>::iterator i = dataTable.begin(); i != dataTable.end(); i++)
{
    cout << *i << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try to implement this in the code(along other things). I will also need to understand half of your code, as parts of it are unfamiliar to me))

Comment: also, how would I search a vector for a team name? I'll post upd to how I did my search before

Comment: @illia, your current search works by O(n). If you're going to search many times you should use **map** instead of vector (`name` as _key_ and some `struct data{double n1, n2, n3}` as _value_). In this way search by name will work by O(log n)

Comment: @Pavel What I need is search to work when I type let's say west ham, instead of West Ham United

Comment: @VolAnd something strange happened. Code was working just fine, but the other time I tried compiling it, and it didn't work(I didn't change anything)

Comment: @illia What do you mean "it doesn't work"? You cannot compile, or result is wrong. Perhaps, it fail with different data on the input, in that case it can be easy to find mistake if you provide me that data.

Comment: @VolAnd I figured it. Had to delete couple lines of your code(when the line is empty) and inFile.clear() in reading data from data. Now it works as I wanted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Divide and conquer.

Divide your relatively complex task into two or more smaller tasks. Then implement each smaller task. Each one of the smaller tasks should be easier on its own merits, then the original task. After implementing each small task, you end up implementing your original task.

Your first step is to read each team, and its scores. This information is given on each line of your input file. So, your first small task is to read one team's worth of information, at a time:

```
std::string teaminfo;

while (std::getline(std::cin, teaminfo).good())
{
    // Here be dragons.
}
```

The "here be dragons" part is where you will take the single line of text that was read into `teaminfo`, and parse it. That will be the next task, but the point is that you've now conquered the first smaller task: reading one team's worth of scores. This is now done. Now, you need to figure out how to extract the individual pieces of data you want. This will be the "here be dragons" part.

As I understand the question, the last three items of information on each line of string are the three scores, separated by whitespaces. And everything else, up to that point, is the team's name.

So the task at hand is to remove the last three whitespace-delimited values from the line. This is also a relatively complex task. So, it also needs to be divided, and conquered as several individual smaller tasks.

The first order of business is to remove any extraneous whitespace at the end of the read line. You did not indicate if it's possible that there's trailing whitespace at the end of the line. If not, this step can be omited. But, if the trailing whitespace needs to be removed, let's do it:

```
while (!teaminfo.empty() && teaminfo[teaminfo.size()-1] == ' ')
   teaminfo=teaminfo.substr(0, teaminfo.size()-1);
```

A rather crude approach, but it's good enough. So now, the trailing whitespace has been trimmed.

Ok, so the remaining task is to remove the last three values on the line. Let's divide this again. Let's start by writing a function that removes the last value from the line, and return it:

```
std::string removeLastValue(std::string &line)
{
   size_t p=line.rfind(' ');

   std::string word;

   if (p == std::string::npos) // Edge case, last word.
   {
        p=0;
        word=line;
   }
   else
   {
        word=line.substr(p+1);
   }

   while (p > 0 && line[p-1] == ' ')
      --p;

   line=line.substr(0, p);

   return word;
}
```

You did not clarify what is your expected result for bad input, when the line is too short, and does not contain a team name with three scores. Here, bad input results in an empty string getting returned.

Anyway, everything after the last space is extracted into `word`; then, a quick loop backs up over the spaces preceding the last word in the `line`, and trims the `line` up to that point. We're done.

The remaining tasks that need to be conquered are now trivial: call this function three times to remove the last three values from the `teaminfo` string. What's left is your team's name, obviously. Also, each removed word is a `std::string`, and you simply need to convert each one to your `double`.

That's something that you should be able to do by yourself, and I don't need to write it out.

Comment: I'm gonna have over 60 similar files, with over 40 doubles in each line(about 20 lines per file), will I have to call a function 40*60*20 times?

Comment: You're going to have to do something 40*60*20 times, unless you manage to break some invariant laws of this universe. Values are not going to extract themselves. Whether an explicit function gets called 40*60*20 times, or `operator>>` gets invoked 40*60*20 times, but something will be executed 40*60*20 times. If you have 40*60*20 values, you will have to do something 40*60*20 times, to get them. You are assuming that `>>` carries no cost, that it's something you get for free. This is false. Actually, `>>` does quite a bit of work.

Comment: Let's say your method works, how do I insert all of the extracted info into a vector?

Comment: The same way anything gets inserted into a vector. `insert()`, `push_back()`, `emplace_back()`, etc...

Comment: in my case I was inserting(adding) the whole object, as my vector is of the object type

Comment: So? What's the problem? Extract all values, and the team name, create an object from them, then insert it exactly like you're doing now.

Comment: Ok, got it, I'll try. Thanks for your help!))